# Apply class name of clicked object to another jQuery

Tags: jquery, toggleclass

I have a function that takes the text and url of a link and inserts it elsewhere when you click it like so:

```
$(document).on( 'click', 'nav a', function( event ) {  
  $("#nav-tabs .ui-tabs-active a").text(this.text);
  $("#nav-tabs .ui-tabs-active a").attr("href",this.href);
  return false
});
```

That works fine. But I also want to grab the classname from it, and I can't figure out the syntax. I tried:

```
$("#nav-tabs .ui-tabs-active a").toggleClass(this.class);
```

But that doesn't work. Suggestions?

Comment: [Element.className](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.className) might be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Use some static "#parent" ID instead of document
$("#parent").on( 'click', 'nav a', function( event ) {  
  event.preventDefault(); // instead of  return false;
  alert( this.textContent +' '+ this.getAttribute("href") +' '+ this.className );
});
```

<sub>Note that `this.href` might return you the full URI path instead of the exact element's `href` attribute value.</sub>

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sh0oarcw/)

or using the respective jQuery methods:

```
$("#parent").on( 'click', 'nav a', function( event ) {  
  event.preventDefault();
  var el = $(this);
  alert( el.text() +' '+ el.attr("href") +' '+ el.attr('class') );
});
```